# MVC 4 get posted primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, get

My question is how to get automatically incremented primary key from POST method in controller1 and use it as a foreign key in GET method in controller2?

currently all the code is generated with EF where I use database first.

I guess I have to edit the GET method in controller2 which looks like this.

```
  // GET: /Question/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TestId = new SelectList(db.Tests, "TestId", "TestTitle");
        return View();
    }
```

This one returns a list of TestTitles

All i need is for it to return the last inserted "testId" or the same inserted "testId" in the current session. Its an integer. How do I do this ?

Comment: Don't increment it, just take LAST_INSERT_ID just after inserting the record and pass it to second controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ActionResult with the same name, since you are not using a model, you just can get the value from the `FormCollection` class

Assuming that you have your `selectlist` was create like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("TestId",ViewBag.TestId);
```

Define another action for the same view like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formData)
{
   formData["TestId"]
   return View();
}
```

Nevertheless I strongly recommended to used a model, and avoid the use of ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id from the object after you save it:

```
db.Foos.Add(foo);
db.SaveChanges();
var pk = foo.Id;
```

As for how to pass this along, assuming you're properly following the GET-POST-Redirect pattern, you'd need to include it in the URL for the redirect somehow. How exactly depends on your action signature and route, but generally you'll do something like the following:

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { id = foo.Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get the ID in the GET method I figured out that I could also find it and use it in the POST Method where I insert the information into database. Finding the last inserted ID with Lambda expression lets me insert the correct value of the foreign key. This will be probably my temporary solution till I improve my structure.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Question question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            question.TestId = db.Tests.OrderByDescending(t => t.TestId).FirstOrDefault().TestId;
            db.Questions.Add(question);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TestId = new SelectList(db.Tests, "TestId", "TestTitle", question.TestId);
        return View(question);
    }`
```